# material text input style has problem with arabic language

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, material-components-android

[image]

As it is shown in the picture , you see the text label is combined with the top line , I need the gap on the right side , how can I acheive that?

Comment: Add Layout code just the one Edit text and style (if there is any) .

Answer (score 0):

One option is downloading a material edittext library from github. I have used the below library and it works fine
https://github.com/florent37/MaterialTextField
Then you can add it as a Module to your project (File -> New -> import module in android studio). The open the layout file and change the floating textview gravity. That's all!
I should note that you don't need to download the entire project, just the folder of the library would be enough(In the above github project, you just need to download materialtextfield folder and then add this folder as a module to your project).
And finally it is Persian, not Arabic :/

Comment: I wasn't sure if anyone knows what persian is , so I mentioned the more famous one ,arabic :D thanks for your time